# Retrieving sub-domain in Next.js page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-typescript

I have a `pages/index.tsx` Next.js page whose code looks like this:

```
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks"
import Client from "../db"

import Header from "../components/Header"

export default function Index() {
    return <ApolloProvider client={Client}>
        <Header langKey={langKey} />
    </ApolloProvider>
}
```

The problem is, `langKey` is supposed to be the sub-domain from which the page is accessed (for instance, `en.localhost:3000` or `fr.localhost:3000`; `langKey` would be `en` or `fr`). How do I retrieve this information from the Next.js context? I tried the Router object, but it doesn't look like it stores any URL information before the first `/`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the `getInitialProps` lifecycle method ([doc's here](https://nextjs.org/docs#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle)) you can access the request object on the server-side and parse the host header.

```
Index.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
  const subdomain = req.headers.host.split('.')[0];
  return { langkey: subdomain };
};
```

If this information is only needed on the client side you could just as easily parse `window.location` somewhere in a lifecycle method with: `window.location.host.split('.')[0]`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: this doesn't seem to work any longer in 2022, the req object has no headers, unless im missing something

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem recently and found a different, simple solution: you can use [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) to put the hostname into the path as a path variable. This works on both server side and client side, though I only tested it with pages that use `getStaticPaths`/`getStaticProps`; there may be issues with other types of page rendering.

Just add something like this to `next.config.js`:

```
        rewrites: async () => {
            // In order to support wildcard subdomains with different content, use a "rewrite" to include the host in the path
            return [
                {
                    source: '/:path*{/}?',
                    has: [
                        {
                            type: 'host',
                            value: '(?<siteHost>.*)',
                        },
                    ],
                    destination: '/site/:siteHost/:path*',
                },
            ];
        },
```

Note 1: This rewrite is used only if the initial request doesn't match a file in `/pages/` so to test it you'll need to move your existing content into the `site` subfolder, e.g. move `pages/index.tsx` to `pages/site/[siteHost]/index.tsx`

Note 2: using `source: '/:path*'` won't work with the homepage (`/`) due to https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/14930 - that's why this uses `source: '/:path*{/}?'`

Comment: Your notes just explained to me why my rewrite wasn't working, thanks! Is this written in docs?